# VBA Excel - if any cells within range

Tags: vba, excel

I need a MsgBox to come up **one time** if any cells in a range (column F in this case) are within a range of numbers (46 and 80). Below is the code I thought would work, but it's not doing anything. I'm pretty sure my If statement is wrong, but I don't know what it needs to be.

```
Sub CheckNumber()
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Dim srchRng As Range

Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set srchRng = Range(Cells(84, 6), Cells(Lastrow, 6))

Dim InputValue As String

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(srchRng) > 46 And WorksheetFunction.CountA(srchRng) < 80 Then
frmCMCapsHS.Show
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean if any cell in the range contains a number between 46 and 80? CountA counts the number of non-empty cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to loop like this:

```
dim c as range    
For Each c In srchRng
        If c.Value > 46 And c.Value < 80 Then
            frmCMCapsHS.Show
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Spelling error in the If statement at `c.value < 80` but I can't edit due to length of fix.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(srchRng) > 46 And WorksheetFunction.CountA(srchRng) < 80 Then
frmCMCapsHS.Show
End If
```

to

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(srchRng, ">46", srchRng, "<80") > 0 Then
frmCMCapsHS.Show
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant way to do this, but you can wrap this in a function and have it loop each cell:

```
Function RangeContains(InputRange As Range, FromVal As Integer, _
    ToVal As Integer) As Boolean

  Dim r As Range
  Dim result As Boolean

  result = False

  For Each r In InputRange
    If r.Value2 >= FromVal And r.Value2 <= ToVal Then
      result = True
      Exit For
    End If
  Next r

  RangeContains = result

End Function
```

And then call it as follows:

```
If RangeContains(Range("F:F"), 46, 80) Then
    frmCMCapsHS.Show
End If
```